# Backspace key doesn't work in Scala REPL on macOS

Tags: java, macos, scala, scala-repl

In macOS Mojave's Terminal, the backspace key doesn't function as it should in the Scala 2.12.7 REPL (installed via Homebrew).

This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/lqtXlKomhgQ) suggests using `scala -Dinput.encoding=iso-8859-1` to start the REPL, however, it doesn't work in this case. I've also tried `scala -Dinput.encoding=utf-8` and `scala -Dinput.encoding=utf-16`.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Same in macOS Catalina with Scala 2.11.12. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I've found that using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) – a better Terminal in many respects – solves this problem completely.

Comment: iTerm2 download didn't work for me. Anyone else with suggestions?